How do I add a bias to the last layer in my model if my model outputs logits and not probabilities?
I'm working on a medical image binary segmentation problem using a U-Net in tensorflow, and my classes are extremely unbalanced (about 1 in 10,000). As a result, my model wastes a ton of time going from predicting 50/50 to the correct distribution.
I want to initialize a good bias for the last layer like in this tutorial, but this tutorial's model outputs probabilities. My model outputs logits without a sigmoid/ReLU/softmax as the last layer, so I'm not sure how I can set the bias.
...
logits = layers.Conv2D(1, (1, 1))(decoder0)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs = [inputs], outputs = [logits])

I tried setting a bias for the logits layer:
output_bias = tf.keras.initializers.Constant(np.log(0.0001))
logits = layers.Conv2D(1, (1, 1), bias_initializer = output_bias)(decoder0)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs = [inputs], outputs = [logits])

But this didn't fix my problem at all, and my model still needed the same amount of time to adjust to the correct distribution.

Adding the same bias to all classes changes nothing, you will have to add different per-class biases.

The model from the link is extremely small, so a bias in the last layer could make a difference. I suppose your U-Net is bigger? I'd look more into class weights (same link, further down). To xdurch0, it seems there is only a binary classification (1 filter in the last layer), so one bias should be enough.
